# div elements (buttons) added with script appear and function, but attributres return undefined

Tags: jquery, undefined, element, innerhtml

This code populates catSelectedDiv based on which input checkboxes `.catInput` were checked in another place.

The `.removeUpdateButtons` divs are added using innerHTML and they appear and seem to function.  That is, their onclick functions get called, and hover action in CSS works.

However, I need to pass their ids along to the click function so the button click can un-select the corresponding checkboxes.

The "business end" of the code is the output+= line.

As shown, alert gives "undefined".  The alert gives undefined for "class" or even ids/classes of `.parent()` and so on selections as well.

```
function clickInput() //for category check box list
{
    var inputSet = document.getElementsByClassName("catInput"); //these are the category checkboxes
    var thisInput;
    var outPut = "";
    var thisLabel;
    for (thisInput = 0; thisInput < inputSet.length; thisInput++)
    {
        if (inputSet[thisInput].checked)
        {
            thisLabel = document.getElementById("L" + inputSet[thisInput].id);
            outPut += '<div id="X' + inputSet[thisInput].id + '" class="removeUpdateButtons" onclick="clickXButton()"></div>' + (thisLabel.innerText || thisLabel.textContent) + '</br>';
        };
    };
    document.getElementById("catSelectedDiv").innerHTML = outPut;
    return;
};

function clickXButton()
{
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
};
```

What I need is to get the identifying info for each div/button into the onclick fn() code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replse `onclick="clickXButton()"` with `onclick="clickXButton(this)"`. And change your function to: 
`function clickXButton(el) {
    alert($(el).attr("id"));
};`

Comment: sweet! that did it.  if you don't mind educating me, how should I have known what I had would fail.  Ive used a shared function like that for "hard coded" sets of 'buttons' and it worked fine.  Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like this

```
function clickInput() //for category check box list
{
    var inputSet = document.getElementsByClassName("catInput"); //these are the category checkboxes
    var thisInput;
    var outPut = "";
    var thisLabel;
    for (thisInput = 0; thisInput < inputSet.length; thisInput++)
    {
        if (inputSet[thisInput].checked)
        {
            thisLabel = document.getElementById("L" + inputSet[thisInput].id);
            outPut += '<div id="X' + inputSet[thisInput].id + '" class="removeUpdateButtons" onclick="clickXButton(this)"></div>' + (thisLabel.innerText || thisLabel.textContent) + '</br>';
        };
    };
    document.getElementById("catSelectedDiv").innerHTML = outPut;
    return;
};

function clickXButton(obj)
{
    alert($(obj).attr("id"));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides a better way to set event handlers. In this case, it would be:

```
...
// remove the onclick handler here
outPut += '<div id="X' + inputSet[thisInput].id + '" class="removeUpdateButtons"></div>' + (thisLabel.innerText || thisLabel.textContent) + '</br>';
...

$(document).on("click", "#catSelectedDiv .removeUpdateButtons", function() {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```